# Matlab Awesome WM

Tags: 12.04, matlab

When i try to start matlab 2013a in ubuntu 12.04 I get only grey window. I found this post http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Problems_with_Java but I dont know where set it up. Please help me

Comment: Have you installed it Using the software center or from the official website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That page instructs you to set an environment variable (`_JAVA_AWT_WM_NONREPARENTING`).

If you start Matlab using a script, then that script would be the best place to do this. Otherwise, you can set this environment variable in your `~/.bashrc` script.

Either way, add the line

```
export _JAVA_AWT_WM_NONREPARENTING=1
```

to the script.